# Is there a way for child component to fill remaining width of page if within a container div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm looking to implement a set of cards that fill the full width of the page.
However, I'd still need the cards to keep within the dimensions of the parent for the left hand side, I only need to 'break' the restrictions of the right-hand side.

Please see image attached to help better explain what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

The left side remains within parent's dimensions, but I need the right-hand side to fill the remainder of the page.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="cards">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
   </div>
</div>



.container{
    max-width:1020px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.cards{
   position:absolute;
   width: 100%; (not sure what to set here to make it fill the remainder of the page instead of just the parent's dimensions)
}

.card{
   width: 268px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: So overflow? Then what? Is this some form of slider? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry if I've not been clear. Forget the slider aspect of it.. I just want the child elements to respect the dimensions of the parent on the left-side only. I want them to be able to go full width from the right

Comment: Well clearly that's not possible. Frankly I would just move the container from the center and align it to the right side, perhaps using left margin. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a grid to set it fully-responsive:

```
    <div class="container">
          <div class="card"></div>
          <div class="card"></div>
          <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    .container{
        max-width:1020px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); // for 3 cards in a row, fully strached

        // OR

        grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, minmax(150px, 300px) ); // for auto-fill the screen, based on min and max size for each card, and the screen size



        grid-auto-rows: 100px; // set all cards height to 100px, can be changed as well

 
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    
    
    .card{
       // to fill the all grid-cell completely 
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
    }
```

If you don’t need to take care of both rows and cols, consider using flex instead of grid.